Given the PDF of X, find the CDF.
Given the PDF of X, which I denote as f(x):
$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{9}(4 - x^2) & \text{if } x \in [-1, 2], \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$.
Show me the steps to get the CDF?

What have you tried? Do you atleast know the definition of a CDF? If yes, then what do you get by applying the definition?

Also, choose your tags carefully. How exactly is "algebra-precalculus" related to this ?

Yes, I know the definition of a CDF.  However, I do not know how to derive the answer via integration.  The last time I picked up a calculus textbook was about 40 years ago.

Hint: use the power rule.

If you're going to be doing more probability, you may want to do a bit of calc review :). You won't see much that doesn't assume a knowledge of differential and integral calculus. Check out Khan Academy, maybe: That's what I used after I had been away from math for ten years.

@dmk or just stick to discrete prob! So many interesting things to think about like markov chains, martingales, random graphs, and branching processes

@dmk - yes, I'm working through the Khan Academy courses right now.  Really great content!

The formula for the CDF is
$$F(y)=\int_{-\infty}^y f(x)dx$$
so we apply this formula. If $y\geq2$, then
$$F(y)=\int_{-1}^{2}\frac{1}{9}(4-x^2)dx = 1$$
When $y\leq-1$
$$F(y)=\int_{-\infty}^y0dx=0.$$
and when $-1< y <2$, we have
$$F(y)=\int_{-1}^y \frac{1}{9}\left(4-x^2\right) d x=\frac{1}{27}\left(-y^3+12 y+11\right).$$
